# Регулярное выражение для валидации формы ввода телефона

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Делал регулярное выражение для валидации формы ввода телефона, по символам все ок. Но мне нужно, чтоб форма сабмитилась, когда введено минимум 7 цифр, а сейчас срабатывает, когда просто 7 символов введено.

Можно ли как-то оставить проверку по символам и изменить условие, чтоб в минимальном количестве учитывало только цифры `[\\+\ \(\\)0-9.-]{7,}`?  Используется в атрибуте pattern тега input.

Comment: @rcd1984, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Задача, которую ставите вы, решается примерно так:

```
var phone = '+ 7 (495) 123-123-12';
if (/\d{7,}/.test(phone.replace(/[\s\+\(\)\-\:\.]/g, ''))) {
    alert('ok');
}
```

Но вообще проверка номера телефона [дело немного более сложное](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/javascript).